# How to calculate the determinant of a matrix NxN ? [Recursively]

Tags: c++

I've been searching in all over the internet for an algorithm to calculate the determinant of NxN martix **recursively**. (I do not have any idea about the dimension, so N can be every integer that is less than 256)

```
complex<double> Matrix::matrixDeterminant(complex<double> **matrix, int n) {

  complex<double> det(0,0);

  complex<double> **submatrix;
  submatrix[i] =  new complex<double>[n]


  for(int i = 0; i< n; i++) {
      submatrix[i] = new complex<double>[n];
    }


   if (n == 2)
      return ((matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[1][0] * matrix[0][1]));
   else {
      for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            int subi = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
               int subj = 0;
               for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                  if (j == x)
                  continue;
                  submatrix[subi][subj] = matrix[i][j];
                  subj++;
               }
               subi++;
            }
            det = det + (pow(-1, x) * matrix[0][x] * matrixDeterminant(submatrix, n - 1 ));
      }

   }
     return det;
}
```

as you can see, the matrix is a Complex matrix which is all the numbers inside are Complex numbers, and also returns complex number.

This method doesn't work. any ideas what to change to make it works?

Comment: What is the algorithm you are trying to implement? Please describe it in detail.

Comment: A first issue: `submatrix` is an array of pointers, not an array of complex. You would avoid such difficulties by using `std::vector` for example.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).

Comment: This is not mine, i just took it from this link [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-compute-determinant-of-a-matrix).

Comment: If you want to implement it as an exercise, it's OK, if you want to use it in practice, don't do it, it's too slow.

Comment: To complete my previous comment: a `delete`is missing at the end of the function ...

Comment: the method above was taken from a link, i just modified a little bit to make it suitable to my class.

Comment: @Damien Well, let's say n + 1.

Comment: Iam implementing it as an exercise :). I don't care about complexity. @Damien can you be more specific ? its a recursive method, where and what exactly i should add delete?

Comment: You don't remove the `ith` raw in the submatrix. Test `i == x` etc.

Comment: You shouldn't copy code that you don't understand. This code will cause memory leaks. Try to find an algorithm and implement it yourself. That's the reason I asked for the algorithm. Try to understand it. You should avoid raw c style arrays and use containers like std:: vector instead to avoid such problems.

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Determinant of matrix with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545044/determinant-of-matrix-with-recursion)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Highly related of course but in my opinion not an exact duplicate as OP wants to know why their code is not working.

Comment: That's why I didn't actually set close as duplicate and just listed it here `:)` Also, unless this has to be "recursive", there are some pretty good Gauss-Jordan eliminations with full-pivoting that can provide the determinate efficiently without recursion.

Comment: @Gladiatorr Each `new` should be paired with a `delete`.  You have a `new` at the begining of the function, add a `delete` at the end of the function. Again, better to use a `std::vector` of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sarrus' Rule (non recursive method) example on below link is in Javascript, but easily can be written in C
https://github.com/apanasara/Faster_nxn_Determinant

nxn Determinant computation thru only two loops